# gnuplot: plot mixed frequency log data with fixed step sizes

Tags: gnuplot

I have a log file with time and value like that:

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 3
6 4
10 4
15 4
20 5
25 5
```

Plotting it (`with linesp`) produces something like this:

```
5|                                 ,----x---------x
4|         ,x-------x---------x---'
3|     ,x-x
2|   ,x  
1|x-x 
 |___________________________________________________
  1 2 3 4 5 6 _ _ _10 _ _ _ _15 _ _ _ _20 _ _ _ _25
```

If I have a lot of values in my file, the left points become very crowded (when using `with linesp`). How can I setup a well defined step size (skipping some of those crowded tuples). For example, I want to plot only one tuple per 5 seconds.

```
5|                                 ,----x---------x
4|          ,-------x---------x---'
3|     ,--x'
2|   ,'  
1|--' 
 |___________________________________________________
  1 2 3 4 5 6 _ _ _10 _ _ _ _15 _ _ _ _20 _ _ _ _25
```

In the end, on those sparse tuples I'd like to add error bars (which I currently have on all points).

Answer (score 1):

You probably could do this using gnuplot's inline function feature, but it would be pretty tricky, and you would never be able to remember what you did to get it to work if you ever wanted to modify it.  Instead, I propose a simple python script to bin/average the data:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sys import argv

d = defaultdict(list)
binsize = 5
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        x,y = [int(xx) for xx in line.split()]
        d[x//binsize].append((x,y))

    for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
        xx,yy = map(sum,zip(*v))
        #print float(xx)/len(v),float(yy)/len(v)  #This version puts x value at average of x points in this bin
        print (k+0.5)*binsize, float(yy)/len(v)  #x value is in middle of bin.
```

It gets passed the datafile as the first argument and then it prints the data to stdout (just like gnuplot likes).  Then your plotting file simply becomes:

```
plot '< python cool_script.py datafile' u 1:2 w lp
```

First, the version with the x-values pushed to the bin centers:

[image]

Now the version with the x-values averaged from all the other x vals in the bin:

[image]

Comment: OK, i guess that's the way to go. But i'd rather use `coffee cool_script.coffee` than python ;). For now I just removed all the points and printed the error as `filledcurve` under the main line (avg), which looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're going for here.  If you have integer points, and you want to put a dot only at points which are divisible by 5, we can do that pretty easily:

```
plot 'foo.txt' u 1:2 w l, '' u (int($1)%5==0?$1:NaN):2 w p ls 1
```

The magic here is done with the ternary operator.  `(int($1)%5 == 0? $1:NaN)` In other words, if the x coordinate is divisible by 5 (after casting to an integer), plot the point, otherwise, don't.

Of course, you're kinda in trouble if your datafile x-points are `1,4,6,12` as none of the points would be plotted (none are divisible by 5).  If that's the case, we can write a real basic script to interpolate to those points using essentially the same technique I used in my other post.

Comment: Unfortunately my x-axis are milliseconds and the log entries do not fit to a perfect fixed stepping.